# How to wait for the internal process of a function to execute completely before returning?

Tags: reactjs, promise, callback, cheerio, asynchronous-javascript

I'm trying to fetch webpages using *axios* and *cheerio* but i'm failing to retrieve all the data as a function is returning even before the intennal process is completely done. I'm using ReactJS and and when i click a button in the page, this function gets called :

```js
analyse = async(e) => {

      this.a = await axios.get('xxx');
      this.s = await axios.get('yyy');
      this.f = await axios.get('zzz');

      let aReturn = this.fetchA(this.a.data);

      let sReturn = this.fetchS(this.s.data);

      let fReturn = this.fetchF(this.f.data);

      if(await fReturn === true && await aReturn === true && await sReturn === true){
            anotherFunction();
      }
}
```

In the above code, the axios works fine and the functions `fetchA()` and `fetchS()` are simple functions without any further internal function calls :

```
fetchA(html){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    //some process

    return true;
}

fetchS(html){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    //some process

    return true;
}
```

The function that is returning without complete execution is `fetchF()` :

```
fetchF(html){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    $('div._someClassName').children().each((i,elem) => {

    let link = $(elem).find('a').first().attr('href');

    axios.get(link)
    .then(response => {

        this.deepF(response.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error : ",err);
     })

    };
    return true;
}
```

In the above function there is a unique link in every child that i need to `axios.get()` again and call another function `deepF()` to grab the data of that page.
The internal function **deepF** is again a small function :

```
deepF(html){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    //some process

    return true;
}
```

In this whole code the `fetchF()` is returning true without completely executing all the `deepF()` functions internally.

*Note : All the `deepF()` functions are executed slowly later after the `fetchF()` returns true*

How can i wait for `fetchF()` to execute all the internal `deepF()` before returning true in `fetchF()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the implementation of `fetchF()` to properly return a promise that is linked to all the ajax calls.  Accumulate the ajax promises into an array and then use `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done.  Then, you can `await` the result of that function.

Change from this:

```
fetchF(html){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    $('div._someClassName').children().each((i,elem) => {

    let link = $(elem).find('a').first().attr('href');

    axios.get(link)
    .then(response => {

        this.deepF(response.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error : ",err);
     })

    };
    return true;
}
```

to this:

```
fetchF(html){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const promises = [];
    $('div._someClassName').children().each((i,elem) => {

        let link = $(elem).find('a').first().attr('href');

        promises.push(axios.get(link).then(response => {
            return this.deepF(response.data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Error : ",err);
            throw err;
        }));
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => true).catch(() => false);
}
```

This makes `fetchF()` into a function that returns a promise that resolves only when all the `axios.get()` calls inside it are done and resolves with a `true` value.  If there are any errors, it catches those errors and resolves with a `false` value (which seems to be the logic you wanted, though it's a bit unusual to not just let the rejected promise propagate and catch it at a higher level to signify errors).

Then, you can use:

```
let fReturn = await this.fetchF(this.f.data);
```

And, then `fReturn` will be `true` or `false`.

---

If any of your other functions have asynchronous operations in them, they will also need to return a promise that is directly linked to your asynchronous operations.